# Using Fable to convert from Fortran 77 to C++

Tags: c++, fortran, converters, fable

I'm just trying to convert a basic helloworld.f program into C++ using fable (in preparation for a bigger program later). I'm getting an error though that says:

```
fable.read.Error: Missing END for PROGRAM:
  at hello.f(1):
  |      program HelloWorld|
```

Which I don't understand as it compiles and runs properly otherwise. The program is just:

```
  program HelloWorld
  implicit none
     write (*,*) 'Hello, world!'   ! This is an inline comment
  end program HelloWorld
```

Does anyone see the issue that fable is finding? I've never used it before so I'm just trying to see how it works. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can't parse `end program HelloWorld`. Try changing it to `end program` or just to `end`.

UPDATE: Indeed, in Fortran 77 everything must end [with just **END**](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-11.html#sh-11.14):

> The END statement indicates the end of the sequence of statements and comment lines of a program unit ( 3.5). If executed in a function or subroutine subprogram, it has the effect of a RETURN statement ( 15.8). If executed in a main program, it terminates the execution of the executable program.
>
> The form of an END statement is:
>
> END
>
> An END statement is written only in columns 7 through 72 of an initial line. **An END statement must not be continued**. No other statement in a program unit may have an initial line that appears to be an END statement.
> **The last line of every program unit must be an END statement**.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with fable on python 2.7.7, you can end your program with either `end` or `end program`, but not with `end program XXXXX`.  This is from what I can tell is due to the way this programs parser works and interprets a match against `program <something>` as a starting program block, even if preceded by `end`.